# Rotate array while maintaining orientation of components in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, bufferedimage

For a project I am working on I have to read a font sprite sheet (font.png as seen bellow) and convert each individual character into an array of indices.

[image]

When reading the file and converting it into an array I use the flowing code:

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Downloads\\font.png"));
    int[][] font = new int[8][760];
    for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) {
            font[j][i] = (img.getRGB(i, j) != - 1) ? 1:0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(font).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
```

Which give me an 8x760 int[][] where each black pixel is a 1 and each white pixel is a 0 (Characters in image are space, !, ", #)
[image]

In an attempt to rotate the array into a 760x8 array I tried the following code:

```
    int[][] rFont = new int[760][8];
    for(int a = 0; a < 95; a++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                rFont[i + 8*a][j] = font[j][i + 8*a];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(rFont).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
```

This code works perfectly to rotate the array except each letter in the font is also rotated 90 degrees. As seen by the following image its clear that the '!' is rotated as well.
[image]

Where did I go wrong in my code to not maintain the orientation of the characters?

Comment: Share font.png :) Maybe  for(int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) instead of for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)  ?

Comment: @JamesMead unfortunately it outputs the same result

Comment: You don't want to rotate the 760 x 8 (width first) array.  You want to segment the 760 x 8 array.  Let's assume that each character has a width of 5 pixels.  You want to create a 5 x 1216 array.  You take each 5 x 8 segment of the original array and stack them one atop the other.  If the character width is not 5, substitute the actual character width.  For a proportional font, you'll have to get the maximum width of the largest character and pad the other characters with zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            rFont[i + 8*a][j] = font[j][i + 8*a];
        }
```

with

```
                for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
                    rFont[i + 8 * a][7 - j] = font[j][i + 8 * a];
                }
```